# MySQL Rank Query Optimise

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

Update the rank column in a table with ties based on the a column value which is alos present on the same table.
Solution: Query should execute within ms.

I have a query which is working perfectly but taking some time to execute ( 1.5 seconds)
Please find the query below and help me to execute it withing ms , table has data in millions.

```
update all_time_leaderboard_rank nlr
    join (
        select id,RANK() over (
            order by `pfp_strength` desc
            ) at_rank
        from all_time_leaderboard_rank
        where standard_test_category_id = 53
          and type = 'pfp_strength'
          and sport_id = 1
        and school_id = '386a06e0-758a-11e9-b57b-ab5b591d14f6'
    ) rt on rt.id = nlr.id
set nlr.`rank` = rt.at_rank
where 1;
```

Comment: Please add the table definition (and especially indexes), e.g. the output of "show create table all_time_leaderboard_rank", and how many rows are matched/updated per query. Also, requiring ms may indicate you do this every time a row is changed. In that case, there might be an option to just change some rows (e.g. if you increase the strength of the current rank 2, only rank 1 and 2 can change at all, and you don't need to calculate rank 3 to 400000), so you may want to add some details regarding this.

Comment: Start by optimizing the SELECT without doing the update.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is guesswork because you didn't describe your tables.

This is a job for a [covering index](https://planetscale.com/learn/courses/mysql-for-developers/indexes/covering-indexes).  You can create an index crafted to accelerate your SELECT query.  This one should do it, if my guess is correct.

```
CREATE INDEX cat_type_sport_school_strength ON all_time_leaderboard_rank
  (standard_test_category_id, type, sport_id, school_id, pfp_strength, at_rank);
```

MySQL (MariaDB too) can random-access this index, in **O**(log(n)) time, to find the first row matching the WHERE in your SELECT, and then scan it sequentially to gather the data needed. It should be faster.

Also, I suggest you end your UPDATE query with

```
set nlr.`rank` = rt.at_rank
where nlr.`rank` <> rt.at_rank
```

instead of `where 1` to avoid updating rows that already have the correct value in the `rank` column.